# Как заставить ansible apt module всегда переустанавливать пакет

Tags: apt-get, ansible

Роль ansible устанавливает нужный пакет с помощью модуля apt. Есть проблема с тем, что разработчик может забыть поменять версию пакета в очередном обновлении и тогда apt проигнорирует обновление.

Сейчас обхожу это условие, напрямую удаляя и устанавливая. Это не очень хорошо, лишний шум в логах.

```
- name: Удаление сервиса
  apt: name=myservice state=absent force=yes

- name: Установка сервиса
  apt: name=myservice state=latest force=yes
```

А можно ли одной задачей этого добиться? Прочитал [доки по apt module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html), но вроде как нет решения.

Конечно, можно напрямую через shell, но тогда в отчете ansible всегда будет `changed: true`

```
- name: Форсированная переустановка сервиса
  shell: apt-get --reinstall install myservice
```

Comment: [How do I force-reinstall a package with ansible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34260658)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кратко: не нужно решать эту проблему с помощью ansible.

Проблема с некорректным версионированием пакета вообще не должна решаться на этом уровне. Нужно реализовывать проверку изменения версии на этапе построения deb-пакета.

В данном случае лучшим из доступных вариантов является уже используемый:

```
- name: Удаление сервиса
  apt: name=myservice state=absent force=yes

- name: Установка сервиса
  apt: name=myservice state=latest force=yes
```